# ZSH completion matching control : fuzzy match on one part of input

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I'm writing a zsh completion for some program, and parts of it involves completing resource routes (`/they/look/like/this`).
I have a command `mycmd` that I can use to generate some completion candidates of resource routes, and provide completions for my program, using:

```bash
_multi_parts '/' "($(mycmd /some/resource/id))"
```

Now, I would like to implement a specific behavior to  match resources that contain the last identifier in my query, not only those that start with it.

For example, `$(mycmd "/resource/identifier/bc")` gives completions like :

```
/resource/identifier/abc456/
/resource/identifier/123abcXYZ/
```

We get resource names whose identifier contains `bc`, which is the intended behavior.

Now here is the problem: zsh completion prevents these completions from showing up, because none of them matches `"/resource/identifier/bc*"`, the default pattern for zsh.

I read the documentation for ZSH `_multi_parts` , [`compadd`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#Completion-Builtin-Commands). It appears that using `-M <pattern>` described in `compadd` doc and available for `_multi_parts` could do the trick, by specifying a custom pattern for completion as described in [ZSH Matching Control documentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#Completion-Matching-Control). However this doc is lacking useful examples and is overall very obscure to me.

I spent hours of trials and errors to find the right pattern argument for `_multi_parts -M <pattern>` to achieve what I want with no success. Any hint on this would be much appreciated.

EDIT: actually, simply ignoring the last resource identifier `bc` would also work. I did not manage to do this either using `-M`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out how to do this. The correct specification is:

```
_multi_parts -M 'l:|=*' '/' $completions
```

The pattern `l:|=*` allows to recognize matches which contain extra character after the string on the command line.
Looking at zsh completion log below (`C-x ?`), we find that it also uses patterns `r:|/=* r:|=*`.
In my understanding, using both `r:|=*` and `l:|=*` allows recognizing any completion candidate -- which is fine in my case, since filtering relevant suggestions is done with `$mycmd`.

Extract from ZSH completion log:

```
+_multi_parts:94> compadd -O tmp1 -M 'r:|/=* r:|=* l:|=*' - ENSG00000170615_SLC26A5_NT
+_multi_parts:96> [[ 1 -eq 0 ]]
+_multi_parts:99> [[ 1 -eq 1 ]]
+_multi_parts:106> [[ SLC = */* ]]
+_multi_parts:109> matches=( ENSG00000170615_SLC26A5_NT/ ) 
+_multi_parts:111> PREFIX=/run/echolocation_example/SLC 
+_multi_parts:112> SUFFIX='' 
+_multi_parts:114> [[ 0 -ne 0 ]]
+_multi_parts:115> zstyle -t :completion::complete:pelican:argument-2: expand suffix
+_multi_parts:119> ((  1  ))
+_multi_parts:120> compadd -p /run/echolocation_example/ -r / -S / -M 'r:|/=* r:|=* l:|=*' - ENSG00000170615_SLC26A5_NT
```